How to delete substring from a URL with .htaccess when it contains a "?"
Eliminate parameters from URLs.
With "..htaccess" on an Apache server, I need to convert URLs like "mydomain.org/FramesVar.html?mypath.html" to "mydomain.org/mypath.html". The "mypath" part are variable paths leading to page names. All other parts of the URL are constant. I've tried a lot of rewrite rules and they never quite work. And I have searched the web in vain. Any ideas? I would prefer to stay within .htaccess. Many thanks in advance.

Basically:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule . /%{QUERY_STRING} [QSD,L]

RewriteCond checks that the query string is not empty. And if that condition is fulfilled, then the RewriteRule will rewrite every request to that query string, discarding the previous query string with the QSD flag.
If necessary, you can also be more specific in which query strings to match - for example, if you only wanted to rewrite if the query string ended in .html, you could do that with
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.html$


I tried this on my website and it doesn't work. I appreciate you taking the time to try to help me.

Did you have a RewriteEngine On first? (Not sure how far into basics we have to go.) Are you getting any server errors? Just nothing happening?

In fact, it does work. I had tried it in conjunction with another rewrite condition and rewrite rule. Apparently, I do not understand how to have sequential rules. When I use your suggestion by itself it works fine. Thanks. In particular, is there a way to conditionally apply different rules for (QUERY_STRING) and no (QUERY_STRING)? Here is the condition and rule I want when there is no (QUERY_STRING). It removes "www." and forces "https://"
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gilbertmunger.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gilbertmunger.org/$1 [R=301]

For "query string empty", you just need to remove the ! that negates the condition - RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$. ^ and $ are regex syntax to anchor the pattern at the start and end of the test string - so this only allows for an empty test string, and nothing else. And multiple sequential RewriteConds are joined by an implict AND (can be changed by using the OR flag if necessary.)

I think I have something that works, but the testers tell me that I have an "unsupported test string".  I want all references to my site to be https and have a domain without "www". And no queries on any URLs. (And old version of the site allowed quires and they are still hanging around in stored links. Here is mu .html that seems to work: rewritebase /
Rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.) https://gilbertmunger.org/%{QUERY_STRING} [QSD,R=301,L]
Rewritecond ^(.) ^www.gilbertmunger.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gilbertmunger.org/$1 [R=301]

Rewritecond ^(.*) ^www\.gilbertmunger\.org$ doesn't make sense, you need to provide an actual value that you want to check the expression against, as the first parameter. If you want to check the request hostname here, use the variable HTTP_HOST - RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gilbertmunger\.org$
